# importing Photoshop files into Illustrator to output AI file

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to create an image for commercial printing. My printer requires an AI file. I have never used Illustrator but am familiar with Photoshop.

Can I make the image in Photoshop, then load it into Illustrator and immediately save as .AI

or

Do i have to make the whole image in Illustrator, from start to finish?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the whole image in Illustrator.

You may find using [Image Trace](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/image-trace.html) helpful.

.ai is just a "wrapper". What's in that wrapper can be vector or raster or a combination. If your print provider needs vector, you can't use the Photoshop file at all other than as a basis for possibly tracing it.

The *best* thing to do would be reconstruct things from scratch. However, not being familiar with Illustrator may present quite a learning curve.

But... it may be helpful to know **why** your print provider is insisting upon an AI file. For traditional commercial printing, Photoshop files should be fine unless they are just poorly set up. And often a print provider may ask for a different format just to make you go away. There are some legitimate reasons a printer may need a vector file though. So without understanding *why* there's an AI requirement it is difficult to be completely definitive.